# Stay at changed directory after using cd command in bat file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Context:

I have a .BAT file with the following code:

```
cd C:\folder1\folder2
subl .
```

When executing that .BAT file in dir "C:/folder3", I want to stay at the navigated directory "C:\folder1\folder2" from my .BAT file.
Now i'm just returning to my previous directory where i've executed that bat file, which is C:\folder3.

This because i want to execute some manual commands in that directory "C:\folder1\folder2"

Comment: Is this the full code of the batch file? if not, are you using `setlocal`?

Comment: No i'm not using setlocal (don't have any experience with bat files..)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pushd`

```
:: to call and make direcoty current
pushd C:\folder1\folder2
subl .
:: go back to your old current working directory
popd
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Both `cd` and `pushd` will both work with any commands you're trying to use within the batch file - the issue here is that when you try to use `subl` it will execute outside of the batch file (ignoring attempts to change the directory). The first thing you're going to want to make sure of is that you have the correct environment variables in place to run Sublime from command.

To do this:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Click System
3. Click Advanced system settings
4. Click Environment Variables...
5. Create a New System variable
6. Name the variable SUBLIME
7. Make the variable value the folder path of your Sublime installation
     (i.e. C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3)
8. Click OK
9. Edit the Path variable located in your User variables
10. Add %SUBLIME% to your variable value (after the `;`)
11. Click OK on all the windows to close them

Even when `subl` will work from command, the issue remains that the `sublime_text.exe` or the `subl.exe` will still run from its home directory - regardless of what current directory is set within your batch. To work around this, you'll need to include your target directory in your `subl` commands so `subl` knows where to go to execute them. You can set your target directory as a variable and use it within the `subl` commands:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\folder1\folder2"
subl "%dir%\targetfileorfolder"
```

Hopefully that helps; it's nothing you're doing wrong in your batch file - it ultimately boils down to the `subl` configuration. I was able to find a semi-relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580924/how-can-i-change-current-working-directory-in-sublime-text-3) for Python, and you may be able to do something similar for cmd/batch if you are comfortable changing those kinds of settings (if they are available at all).

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Thanks - I've changed it to be more answer-y.